# Función que cambie cada mes, ¿Cómo puedo hacer una especie de setInterval que el delay sea 1 mes?

Tags: javascript, date

Tengo un *Tooltip* que dice que la fecha de la oferta es de 24 de Marzo a 24 de Mayo.

Me pidieron que esa fecha se auto-renueve cada un mes, entonces ya tengo las funciones para que se renueve, el problema es que había pensado poner el tiempo en milisegundos que corresponden a un mes en *setInterval*, para que me renueve la fecha cada un mes y *setInterval* no acepta un número de milisegundos tan grandes.

¿Cómo puedo hacer una función que se renueve cada un mes?

```
<p>Desde el 
        <span id="initialDateSpan"></span> 
        hasta el 
        <span id="finalDateSpan"></span>
    </p>

    const day = '24';
        const monthStart = '03';
        const monthEnd = '04';
        const year = '2022';
        let miliseconds = 5000;
const initialDateSpan = document.querySelector('#initialDateSpan');
const finalDateSpan = document.querySelector('#finalDateSpan');

//Inicialización de fechas
        let initialDate = new Date(`${year}-${monthStart}-${day}`)
let initialDay = initialDate.getDate()
        let initialMonth = ("0"+(initialDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
        let initialYear = initialDate.getFullYear()
let finalDate = new Date(`${year}-${monthEnd}-${day}`)
let finalDay = finalDate.getDate()
        let finalMonth = ("0"+(finalDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
        let finalYear = finalDate.getFullYear()

if(initialDateSpan){
            initialDateSpan.innerText = `${initialDay}/${initialMonth}/${initialYear}`
        }
if(finalDateSpan){
            finalDateSpan.innerText = `${finalDay}/${finalMonth}/${finalYear}`
        }

 //Funciones cambiar fecha
        const changeDateCurrent = () => {
            initialDate.setMonth(initialDate.getMonth() + 1);
            initialDay = initialDate.getDate()
            initialMonth = ("0"+(initialDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
            initialYear = initialDate.getFullYear()
            
            return `${initialDay}/${initialMonth}/${initialYear}`
        }

const changeDateNext = () => {
            finalDate.setMonth(finalDate.getMonth() + 1);
            initialDay = finalDate.getDate()
            initialMonth = ("0"+(finalDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
            initialYear = finalDate.getFullYear()

            return `${initialDay}/${initialMonth}/${initialYear}`
        }


setInterval(() => {
            if(initialDateSpan){
                initialDateSpan.innerText =  changeDateCurrent()
            }
            
            if(finalDateSpan){
                finalDateSpan.innerText =  changeDateNext()
            }`introducir el código aquí`
            
        }, miliseconds

)
```

El problema es que *setInterval* no abarca un mes en milisegundos.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que entiendas como funciona el sitio. Por favor, [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el código que has intentando.

Comment: No acabo de entender... ¿Esperas que alguien tenga abierta esa web durante un mes sin cerrar, cambiar de página, apagar, etc? No entiendo qué significa que "esa fecha se autorenueve cada un mes". ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo? Quizá más bien te conviene poner un interval que cada cierto tiempo compruebe qué fecha es, y la actualice si es mayor que cierta fecha (cada hora compruebo qué fecha es, y si ha pasado más de un mes desde x, actualizo el tooltip).

Comment: Actualmente dice "Desde el 24-03 hasta el 24-04", ahora bien, el dia 24-04 debe renovarse la funcion que le suma un mes  a la fecha actual para que diga "desde el 24-04 hasta el 24-05" y asi se vaya sumando siempre un mes cada un mes

Comment: Si es un tooltip imagino se activara al hover o click de algun otro elemento. ahi es un buen momento para hacer un metodo que compruebe la fecha

Comment: si, no habia pensado en hacerlo durante el evento del hover, pero es una opcion buena

Answer (score 1):

Como dije en el comentario, te sugiero que hagas un intervalo más corto, que periódicamente compruebe la fecha, y la actualice si ve que es mayor de lo esperado.

En este ejemplo, un interval cada segundo comprueba si han los segundos de la hora actual son múltiplos de 10. En tu caso, sería lo mismo, pero comprobar si ha pasado un mes, y quizá hacer la comprobación menos de una vez por segundo.

```js
var options = { hours: 'numeric', minutes: 'numeric', seconds: 'numeric' };

setInterval(() => {
  const horaActual = new Date();
  const horaString = horaActual.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById('hora-actual').textContent = horaString;
  
  if (horaActual.getSeconds() % 10 === 0) {
    document.getElementById('multiplo-10').textContent = horaString;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  Hora actual: <span id="hora-actual"></span>
</div>
<div>
  Último múltiplo de 10: <span id="multiplo-10"></span>
</div>
```

Deberías tener en cuenta que `setInterval` no garantiza que el tiempo pasado sea el que tu has puesto. Por ejemplo:

- Si el ordenador se suspende, el intervalo se paraliza. Puedes ponerle un intervalo de 5 minutos, si después de 2 minutos lo suspendes y lo vuelves a encender una hora después, el interval no va a ejecutar hasta al menos 3 minutos más.
- En intervalos cortos, si una página está en segundo plano, el intervalo es probable que sea más lento. Por ejemplo, en intervalos de menos de 1 segundo, al menos Chrome los ralentiza a 1 segundo.
- La clase `Date` de JavaScript usa la hora del dispositivo. Si en tu dispositivo pones la hora del mes que viene, JavaScript se creerá que estás en el mes que viene.

Comment: el problema que veo es que deberia estar un año minimo renovando la fecha de un mes en un mes

Comment: Yo ahí no veo problema, el intervalo se irá ejecutando con la frecuencia que le digas. Pero ten en cuenta que el JS solo se va a ejecutar mientras el ordenador esté en la página. ¿De verdad va a haber alguien con la página abierta durante meses y meses?